# Fill boxplot color based on value gradient

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to color the boxplot based the value on `y` axis using a `color gradient`. I added the legend filled with red to blue gradient but I don't know how to add those colors into each box.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))+ geom_boxplot(aes(colour = hwy))+
 scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red", high = "blue", 
   midpoint = 25, limit = c(0,50), space = "Lab", 
   name="hwy")
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to fill by the y-axis value since the boxplot is based on all of the values in the class.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can. ggplot [documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_boxplot.html) only mentions coloring by a factor, and I see only factor that has been specified on x axis.

Also when you think about it your statement is ambigious, what in the box plot determines `fill`? Median, Upper Boundary, Lower Boundary?

Update:

This isn't exactly what you asked for but its close.

```
mpg %>% 
  group_by(class) %>% 
  mutate(mean.hwy= mean(hwy)) %>% 
  ggplot( aes(class, hwy)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    stat_summary(fun.y= "mean",
                 aes(y=mean.hwy,color=mean.hwy),
                 geom = "point") +
    scale_color_gradient2(low = "red", 
                          high = "blue", 
                          midpoint = 25, 
                          limit = c(0,50), 
                          space = "Lab", 
                          name="hwy")
```

For some reason I couldn't get this to work with median which I guess would make more sense here but hopefully this will get you closer to your goal.

Comment: I know, but my goal is just adding some extra information on box plot. The code I referred to is just an example.

Comment: I agree with @sgp667, you cannot fill by a value that doesn't exist. Each box in the boxplot represents many values of that class, there is no specific value to point to.

Comment: @Geo-sp Filling by a color gradient wouldn't add any information , but if you want a more continuous visualization of a distribution along y, consider taking a look at `geom_violin`